# Libreoffice Calc: Apply two conditional formats at the same time?

Tags: libreoffice, conditional-formatting

I have a work-logging spreadsheet where column B contains a date and I want to add two conditional formats:

- If column "B" is a monday, make the border line above thicker. (In order to mark the beginning of the new week).
- If column "B" is the current date (`$B1=TODAY()`), the background color should be yellow. (In the screenshots I use the condition `ISODD(DAY($B2))` instead.)

There are three options I assumed might do this, but two don't work and one is fragile as more formattings are added.

Is it possible to obtain the desired behavior in a manner that scales better than option #3 below?

## 1. Multiple conditional formattings: Doesn't work.

- In "Format > Conditional Formatting > Manage", add separate conditional formattings but specify the range to be the same.

This would be much more maintainable, but it looks like only the last matching condition is applied. Whats worse, it isn't possible to rearrange the order of conditions to better approximate the needs.

[image]

## 2. Multiple conditions: Doesn't work.

- Define single conditional formatting for the range.
- Add an entry for each condition and formatting.

This fails, because only the first matching condtion will be considered.

[image]

## 3. Compound conditions: Works, but doesn't scale.

- Define a single conditional formatting for the range.
- Inside that conditional formatting, define three cases and a separate formatting for each of them:

  1. Both "Monday" and "today"
  2. Monday
  3. Today

This works, because for a single conditional formatting only the first matching condition is applied. It does however scale badly, as it requires maintaining a separate condition and formatting for each combination.

At two conditions, this still is reasonable, but if I need a third condition (e.g. change font color for legal holidays) I'd already need 7 conditions and associated formattings, that need to be kept consistent: Generally for N conditions, I'd need 2<sup>N</sup>-1 cases (all combinations, except for the case, where none of the conditions applies).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Conditional formatting is generally preferred over macros. However, if the number of conditions and formatting becomes unmanageable due to the exponential number of formattings required, then write a macro instead.

In the Basic example below, if a cell is both greater than 5 and equal to 7 then both formatting changes will be applied. Right-click on the sheet tab, select *Sheet Events* and assign it to the *Content Changed* event.

```vb
Sub MultipleConditionalFormatting(oSheetCellRanges As Object)
    If oSheetCellRanges.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCell") Then
        oCellAddress = oSheetCellRanges.getCellAddress()
        oDoc = ThisComponent
        oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(oCellAddress.Sheet)
        oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(oCellAddress.Column, oCellAddress.Row)
        oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(oSheetCellRanges.AbsoluteName)
        oCellRange.clearContents(_
            com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.HARDATTR OR _
            com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.STYLES OR _
            com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.EDITATTR)
        If oCell.getValue() > 5 Then
            oCell.CellBackColor = RGB(255,141,56)
        End If
        If oCell.getValue() = 7 Then
            oCell.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.ULTRABOLD
            oCell.CharHeight = "18"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Result - notice that `7` has both formats applied:

[image: list of numbers with two overlapping formatting rules]

A longer discussion is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=89169. The link includes an elegant but advanced python example that sets the formatting using [setDataArray()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sheet_1_1XCellRangeData.html) for a general-purpose solution.

Regarding the order, in [LO 5.4.5 and later](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74074), rearrange the conditions by using the up/down buttons.

[image: up/down buttons for conditional formatting]

Comment: Regarding the order, reordering isn't available for #1. (LO 6.1.3.2)